# Erro "arquivo fonte não compilado"

Tags: c++, dev-c++

Estou usando o Dev-C++. Compilo e quando vou executar aparece a mensagem:

> arquivo fonte não compilado

O que estou fazendo de errado?

```
#include <stdio.h>
main()
{
    float lado, area ;
    cout<< "digite o lado";
    cin>> lado;
    area= lado*lado;
    cout<< area;

  system("PAUSE");  
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Quando tiver outros problemas e for fazer outras perguntas, coloque mais detalhes. Este é um caso muito simples e deu para perceber logo o que tinha de errado, mas na maioria dos casos se não colocar tudo o que está usando, descrever o que está tentando fazer, dar detalhes, mostrar o erro que ocorre, onde, quando, etc. a pergunta será fechada por não estar clara, até você melhorá-la.

Comment: Dê uma olhada no [tour]. Você pode aceitar uma resposta se ela resolveu seu problema. Você pode votar em todos os posts do site também. Alguma lhe ajudou mais? Precisa que algo seja melhorado?

Answer (score 2):

Você está misturando C com C++. A primeira coisa a fazer é decidir se vai programar em uma linguagem ou na outra. Como parece ser C++, vou tentar acertar para ela:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    float lado;
    cout << "digite o lado";
    cin >> lado;
    float area = lado * lado;
    cout << area;
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](http://ideone.com/cmevJv). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/btboqsff-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CPP/Console/Area.cpp).

As mudanças que eu fiz:

- Coloquei o cabeçalho certo, o `iostream` que contém o `cin` e `cout`. O que está usando é cabeçalhop de C.
- Coloquei um `using` para não ter que chamar o método pelo nome completo, assim não precisa usar `std::cin`, por exemplo.
- E acertei o tipo da função `main()` que retorna um `int`, então tem que tipar ela.

Depois se quiser pode melhorar para a saída ficar mais apresentável.

Dei uma organizada no código também. Acostume-se fazer isto. É importante.

Consertando essas coisas deve compilar. O meu compilou. Não sei no DEV C++ porque é um IDE bem ruim.

Comment: +1 pela explicação correcta. Talvez fosse interessante complementar a resposta com as razões pelas quais considera que o DEV C++ não é um bom IDE.

Comment: @AlexandreCartaxo Acho que não caberia aqui. Precisaria de uma pergunta específica. Mas teria que ser muito bem feita pra não ser ampla ou baseada em opiniões.